# ListView and MapActivity under Tab using classes

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-widget

I am trying to put a MapActivity and a ListActivity in Tabs. I found a way of doing it, but I just don't like the way it looks like (I rather use some classes to make my code more modular)

Now, I have this code in my main activity:

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables      
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, OptionsActivity.class);

 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OPTS_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("Options",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_options))
                          .setContent(intent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

And this one in the OptionsActivity class:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OptionsActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

String[] options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options_array);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options));  

ListView lv = getListView();

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.opt);
lv.setEmptyView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.options));

lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options));


}

}
```

and my layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/main">
                <ListView 
                    android:id="@+id/list" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip" 
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/empty" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <ListView 
                    android:id="@+id/opt" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip" 
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/options" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/mainlayout" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapview" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:apiKey="0fFbO-eNMhj2lDaC6b4YBfpo1DikBMixPYiEJCw" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

But for some reason, when I select this "Options" tab, my application has a force close...

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @lmperian You have both list and map in one activity??

Answer (score 0):

you are not using any layout so from where you are getting `lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.opt);` put code in try catch block like this
     try{
     ListView lv = getListView();

```
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.opt);
 lv.setEmptyView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.options));
 lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
 lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options));
 }catch(Exception e){
 e.getMessage();       ///Put break point here to find error
  }
```

**then debug it once**

Comment: I am using a layout, I've just updated the question with it, my fault :p

Comment: i am talking about ListActvity.there is no layout from which you can get lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.opt);